# Search on phone number in AD

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to search in LDAP who has their phonenumber set? (as in, everybody without a NULL value as phone will be shown?)

**edit**: without knowing the usernames beforehand..

Comment: Figured it out myself by playing around abit, for any1 curious:

     $filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(telephoneNumer=*))';

Does the trick! :)

Comment: Put it as answer, it's the good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself by playing around abit, for any1 curious:

```
$filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(telephoneNumber=*))';
```

Does the trick